# X11/SSH issues "wrong authentication"

Tags: ssh, remote-desktop

I've been having issues getting X11 to work lately - several hours of googling and trying various fixes have got me nowhere.  Here's the specifics:

- I am trying to log in to a department computer from my laptop via `ssh -X` over the local network.  X11 worked perfectly for quite some time, then all of a sudden I started getting the error message: `X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication`
- I have tried about 6 different things to remedy this.  I thought I had it working last week by modifying my local copy of `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`, specifically I uncommented the line `ForwardX11Trusted yes`.  This apparently was a fluke because now it isn't working again
- I have also tried adding my MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE to the remote machine using xauth add, but this hasn't seemed to work.
- Tried everything [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/x11-connection-rejected-because-of-wrong-authentication/), in particular I have permissions for `.Xauthority` and my discs are nowhere near full (local and remote).

Here are the outputs of my various environment variables and so forth:

```
$ echo $DISPLAY # local machine 
:0.0

$ echo $DISPLAY # remote machine
localhost:10.0

$ xauth list # local
laptop/unix:0 MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 45f1f58762e8040da75508d23df6819e

$ xauth list # remote
# blank
```

I image this last one is the key, but repeated attempts at xauth add on the remote machine don't seem to change this.

Any ideas?  Let me know if I can provide any more outputs.  Thanks!

Comment: "local machine" is typically called the client. "remote machine" is called the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ended up being an Occam's Razor: the simplest explanation *was* true:

```
$ df -H
Filesystem             Size   Used  Avail Use% Mounted on
grad2:/u6/#username   247G   113G   121G  49% /u6/#username
```

Looks like I have tons of room, right?  Well, turns out I actually have a quota on that disc, which turned out to be full:

```
$ quota
Disk quotas for user #username (uid #####): 
     Filesystem  blocks   quota   limit   grace   files   quota   limit   grace
grad2:/u6/#username
            1698264  1700000 1700000           12742       0       0
```

Cleared out a few files, had the admin increase the quota, and *viola:*  X11 works again.  Why on earth couldn't it have a *useful* error message like "cannot start X11 because your quota/disc is full"??  I probably wasted 5 hours on this.

Comment: Viola is an instrument :P

Comment: Didn't expect this to be my issue, but it was. I presumed the trashed files (from deleting via the OS's GUI) would automatically be removed when I approached the quota, but apparently that's not the case.

Answer (score 8):

You can get this error due to several problems:

1 - Running out of disk space. Check you available space (on the server) with `df`

```
df -H
```

If you are low on disk space remove unnecessary files from your system.

2 - `~/.Xauthority` needs proper ownership and permissions

```
ls -l ~/.Xauthority
```

you can set proper permissions as needed (you may need sudo if the file is owned by root).

```
chown you_user:your_group ~/.Xauthority
chmod 0600 ~/.Xauthority
```

3 - Make sure X Forwarding Enabled. You need a capital X with `ssh -X` . In addition, on the server

```
grep X11Forwarding /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

should show

> X11Forwarding yes

4 - Make sure X11 client forwarding enabled

On your client, /etc/ssh/ssh_config should have the lines:

> Host *
>   ForwardX11 yes

Then

```
ssh -X user@server
```

should work.

Comment: Thanks! I figured it out - my quota was full and df -H didn't let me know.