# X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication

Tags: ssh, sshd, x11-forwarding

I recently installed `fbprophet` via conda on python. Whenever I am trying to import it, my ipython environment crashes with follwowing error.

```
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.                                                                                                     
qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display analytics-lab:10.0
Could not connect to any X display.
```

I have already opened a bug on github for the same. https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/887

However, this issue seems more system configuration specific than `fbprophet` issue. Since I have seeing `X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.` error for long time.

I have already tried deleting the .Xauthority file from server and relogin with ssh -X user@host, but it did not solve the problem.

I have tried to the change the configuration as per suggestions mentioned here as well. [X11/SSH issues "wrong authentication"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377053/x11-ssh-issues-wrong-authentication)

On server side

```
df -h
/dev/sdc1        50G   34G   14G  73% /


ls -l ~/.Xauthority
-rw------- 1 xxx xxx 50 Mar 15 00:35 /home/prashant/.Xauthority


grep X11Forwarding /etc/ssh/sshd_config
X11Forwarding yes
```

On client side:

```
Host *
    ForwardX11 yes
```

There is no quota on the server.

I have also tried setting `DISPLAY=0` as suggested at many places. But it also does not work.

Can anyone suggest what might be causing this issue and how to fix it?

P.S. I see this message even when I exit vim and I also can't open any gui based output. It failed with the same error. 
P.S. Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: What OS and which X server is running on the system from which you are SSHing from?

Comment: On server - xorg-server 2:1.18.3-1ubuntu2.3~trusty4
On client - xorg-server 2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.1~16.04.2